# Why the type of constant is 2.8 in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I was learning Typescript and found out that this constant has type 2.8, `const num = 2.8` but why doesn't it have 'number' type

Comment: 2.8 is the value, how did you figure out that the num constant doesn't have "number" type?

Comment: How did you find that type is 2.8?

Answer (score 1):

`2.8` is the [numeric literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) that holds only exactly the value `2.8`.

Since `num` is `const` it can't ever hold a different value. so that type is perfectly applicable to `num`.

Note that you can *assign* a `2.8`-type value to a `number` variable.

A common use of literal types are things like

```
type sortDirection = "ascending" | "descending";
```

Here we use (string) literal types together with union types to construct a type that can hold only the two strings mentioned in its definition.